# Anybody know of this bug in jQuery Address plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, hashchange, jquery-address

Using jQuery Address plugin, if i create 2 bookmarks on IE 7 or 8:

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/api/#/section/?id=1&name=n1&name=n2

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/api/#/section/2

now i go to google.com (or any other website) first, and then i visit bookmark 1 above, and then bookmark 2 above, and click "Back", it will bring me back directly back to Google, instead of going back to bookmark 1's URL first.  (the Ajax history and bookmark feature).  This is true on IE 7 and 8, but ok on Chrome and Firefox.

Anybody know of tweak / hack / fix to make this work?  So far I have tried Really Simple History, jQuery History, Ajaxify as well, and none of them is bug free.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but this is an unpleasant issue with IE. It seems that there is a workaround for IE7 because it was working properly in jQuery Address 1.0 but there is no reliable solution for IE8.

I just submitted the following bug to the IE team:
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/576384/navigating-to-a-hash-anchor-using-the-address-bar-does-not-create-a-history-entry

Comment: seems like a working solution can be jQuery History plugin with this fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261516/can-someone-who-is-very-familiar-with-jquery-and-javascript-confirm-this-jquery-h  but would help if there is further comment or change suggestions.  thanks.

Comment: Can you please try the latest version at GitHub[1]. It should fix the IE7 issue but at the moment I can't find a clean workaround for IE8.


1. http://github.com/asual/jquery-address/raw/master/src/jquery.address.js